# Deploying laravel 8 app on shared hosting folder structure

Tags: laravel, github, deployment, github-actions, shared-hosting

How can I deploy laravel 8 application via git access with new folder structure on shared hosting for laravel 8 applications? (hostinger)

As I know for laravel 8 you need to separate project folder and public folder to public_html for example. I'm not sure why structure have to be like this, older versions were deployed with whole application to public_html folder.

My question is how can I deploy application with this structure when I deploy my github repository? In my github repo structure is not same as I need on shared hosting?

Comment: I personally install in a new directory outside of public_html, and replace public_html with a symlink to the laravel public folder.

Comment: Seems like a solution! Did you tried to use git actions after every push on master for example, with this way of doing? Is it working as expected? Thanks for response! @GertB.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple applications working that way, you just use your git commands in the application folder

Comment: @GertB. Cool, thanks!